# Increase MaxReceivedMessageSizeProperty

Tags: wcf, mobile, web-config

I'm doing one mobile application and while calling one web service, I'm getting  MaxReceivedMessageSize error. It says this value should be increased.

[image]

I read that we can find this property in the WCF web config file and there we should increase the value.

But one web application is also using the same service and it is receiving the response. So Is the issue in mobile application happening because of the value in web config file or Do i need to set anything in the mobile app side to take care of this.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

first, check the client side code and see if the service API is called with wrong value. i mean whether the big request message is normal for the application.

second, try to increase the value at server side and see if it solves the issue. e.g.

```
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="bigger value">
                ...
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
```

third, for the web application which uses the same service and receives response, can you double-check if web app and the mobile app use the same service (e.g. different endpooint)?